# How to run a Jupyter notebook with Python code automatically on a daily basis?

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, scheduled-tasks, papermill

I have some Python code in a Jupyter notebook and I need to run it automatically every day, so I would like to know if there is a way to set this up. I really appreciate any advice on this.

Comment: Can't you convert the notebook into a Python file and just run that periodically?  Does it have to be enclosed in a notebook?  Another important question is what is the code supposed to do?

Comment: Just put it in a regular `.py` file and then have a built in scheduler type program (i.e. windows task scheduler) run whenever you need.

Comment: I need to run as is bc it call several notebooks so it basically the motor of a bigger engine

Comment: If you really want to do it this way, take a look at Jupyter's Execute API: http://nbconvert.readthedocs.io/en/latest/execute_api.html#executing-notebooks-from-the-command-line. You can run Jupyter notebooks in the command line, and you can combine this with a scheduling program or an automated script that will run what you need and how often you need to run it.

Comment: Is there a particular reason for running the code in Jupyter notebook?

Comment: yes is an etl code

Comment: @rayryeng has a good solution. Figure out the command needed to run it, stick that in a batch file, then call the batch file from the scheduler program.

Comment: I have that but and in spite that run every day , sometimes run but like a ghost I mean don't pull the info that i need

Comment: @BetsyCurbelo can you clarify ?

Comment: well I have a cmd file that its supposed to run everyday, my code takes daily info from one place to a database, and for example I have the info for 02/10 but not the info for 02/11

Comment: @BetsyCurbelo So there's an issue with your code? If not, just create a scheduled task that runs that file.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's better to combine with airflow if you want to have higher quality. 
I packaged them in a docker image, https://github.com/michaelchanwahyan/datalab.

It is done by modifing an open source package nbparameterize and integrating the passing arguments such as execution_date. ***Graph can be generated on the fly*** The output can be updated and saved within inside the notebook.

When it is executed

- the notebook will be read and inject the parameters
- the notebook is executed and the output will overwrite the original path

Besides, it also installed and configured common tools such as spark, keras, tensorflow, etc.

Comment: what about security?

Answer (score 36):

**Update**
recently I came across papermill which is for executing and parameterizing notebooks.

https://github.com/nteract/papermill

```
papermill local/input.ipynb s3://bkt/output.ipynb -p alpha 0.6 -p l1_ratio 0.1
```

This seems better than nbconvert, because you can use parameters. You still have to trigger this command with a scheduler. Below is an example with cron on Ubuntu.

---

**Old Answer**

```
nbconvert --execute
```

can execute a jupyter notebook, this embedded into a cronjob will do what you want.

**Example setup on Ubuntu:**

Create *yourscript.sh* with the following content:

```
/opt/anaconda/envs/yourenv/bin/jupyter nbconvert \
                      --execute \
                      --to notebook /path/to/yournotebook.ipynb \
                      --output /path/to/yournotebook-output.ipynb
```

You have more options except --to notebook. I like this option since you have a fully executable "log"-File afterwards.

I recommend using a virtual environment to run your notebook, to avoid that future updates mess with your script. Do not forget to install nbconvert into the environment.

Now create a cronjob, that runs every day e.g. at 5:10 AM, by typing `crontab -e` in your terminal and add this line:

```
10 5 * * * /path/to/yourscript.sh
```

Answer (score 5):

Try the [SeekWell Chrome Extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/seekwell/mefkdbekccdbdihhondepjimindlbpfg).  It lets you schedule notebooks to run weekly, daily, hourly or every 5 minutes, right from Jupyter Notebooks.  You can also send DataFrames directly to Sheets or Slack if you like.

Here's a [demo video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cNnjSGaFVC4), and there is more info in the Chrome Web Store link above as well.

**Disclosure:  I'm a SeekWell co-founder

Comment: Right now, the startar plan costs 50 dollars per month: https://www.seekwell.io/pricing

Answer (score 3):

As others have mentioned, papermill is the way to go. Papermill is just `nbconvert` with a few extra features.

If you want to handle a workflow of multiple notebooks that depend on one another, you can try [Airflow's integration with papermill](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/stable/howto/operator/papermill.html). If you are looking for something simpler that does not need a scheduler to run, you can try [ploomber](https://github.com/ploomber/ploomber) which also integrates with papermill (Disclaimer: I'm the author).

Answer (score 2):

you can add jupyter notebook in cronjob

```
0 * * * * /home/ec2-user/anaconda3/bin/python /home/ec2-user/anaconda3/bin/jupyter-notebook
```

you have to replace /home/ec2-user/anaconda3 with your anaconda install location, and you can schedule time based on your requirements in cron

Answer (score 2):

Executing Jupyter notebooks with parameters is conveniently done with [Papermill](https://github.com/nteract/papermill/). I also find convenient to share/version control the notebook either as a Markdown file or a Python script with [Jupytext](https://github.com/mwouts/jupytext). Then I convert the notebook to an HTML file with `nbconvert`. Typically my workflow looks like this:

```sh
cat world_facts.md \
| jupytext --from md --to ipynb --set-kernel - \
| papermill -p year 2017 \
| jupyter nbconvert --no-input --stdin --output world_facts_2017_report.html
```

Learn more about the above, including how to specify the Python environment in which the notebook is expected to run, and how to use continuous integration on notebooks, have a look at my article *Automated reports with Jupyter Notebooks (using Jupytext and Papermill)* which you can read either on [Medium](https://medium.com/capital-fund-management/automated-reports-with-jupyter-notebooks-using-jupytext-and-papermill-619e60c37330), [GitHub](https://github.com/CFMTech/jupytext_papermill_post/blob/master/README.md), or on [Binder](https://mybinder.org/v2/gh/CFMTech/jupytext_papermill_post/master?filepath=README.md). Use the Binder link if you want to test interactively the outcome of the commands in the article.

Answer (score 2):

To run your notebook manually:

```
jupyter nbconvert --to notebook --execute /home/username/scripts/mynotebook.ipynb
```

Create a simple batch file and add the command above to the file:

```
/home/username/scripts/mynotebook.sh
```

Paste the command above into the file

Make the file executable

```
chmod +x /home/username/scripts/mynotebook.sh
```

To schedule your notebook use cron or airflow, depends on your needs vs complexity. if you want to use cron, you can simply do crontab -e and add an entry

```
00 11 * * * /home/username/scripts/mynotebook.sh
```

Answer (score 2):

There are several ways to [execute a Jupyter Notebook daily](https://mljar.com/blog/schedule-jupyter-notebook/), according to the article.

### Cron or Windows Task Scheduler

You can use your operating system scheduler to execute the notebook. There are two command line tools for executing notebooks:

- [nbconvert](https://github.com/jupyter/nbconvert)
- [papermill](https://github.com/nteract/papermill)

Both are great, I personally use `nbconvert`, but `papermill` offers handful of extensions as input parameters for notebooks or automatic export to cloud storage.

### Mercury

The open source framework [Mercury](https://github.com/mljar/mercury) is a web based application that:

- can execute notebook in the background,
- can share notebook as website,
- can send execute notebook as email with PDF or HTML attachment,
- can restrict access to notebooks to authenticated users.

##### Notebooks available in web app

[image: list of notebooks in Mercury]

##### Scheduled notebook

[image]

##### PDF notebook sent in email

[image: example pdf notebook sent in email]

### Notebooker

[Notebooker](https://github.com/man-group/notebooker) is open source web app for scheduling and sharing notebooks.

##### List of notebooks

[image: list of notebooks]

##### Executed notebook

[image: notebooker executed notebook]

Answer (score 0):

You can download the notebook in the form of .py and then create a batch file to execute the .py script. Then schedule the batch file in the task scheduler

Answer (score 0):

Creating a BAT file then running it through Task scheduler worked for me. Below is the code.

```
call C:\Users\...user...\Anaconda3\condabin\conda activate
python -m notebook_file.py
pause
call conda deactivate
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply put this line in `crontab -e`

`0    1   *    *    * jupyter nbconvert --to html --execute /path/to/main.ipynb`

This will execute your julyter notebook every day at 1:00 am.

Answer (score -3):

You want to use [Google AI Platform Notebooks](https://cloud.google.com/ai-platform-notebooks) Scheduler service currently in EAP.