# How do i automate my jupyter notebook using google cloud?

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, automation, jupyter-notebook, gcp-ai-platform-notebook

I have a code with Jupyter notebook and i would like to schedule daily running by Google Cloud.

I already created VM instance and running my code there, 
but I couldn't find any guide or video how to implement daily running.

So, how can I do that?

Comment: See if this helps [How to run a jupyter notebook daily](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48750055/how-to-run-a-python-jupyter-notebook-daily-automatically)

Answer (score 2):

Google is offering a product which is called [AI Platform Notebooks](https://cloud.google.com/ai-platform-notebooks/). It is implementing lots of useful stuff like lots of open-source frameworks, CI etc. There is also a blog post by the Google Cloud that explains the product in depth and can be found [here](https://cloud.google.com/blog/products/ai-machine-learning/best-practices-that-can-improve-the-life-of-any-developer-using-jupyter-notebooks). I think you can use that to achieve what you want.

Answer (score 0):

You can use cron to schedule the notebook in the VM machine. Please take a look at [nbconvert](https://github.com/jupyter/nbconvert) or [papermill](https://github.com/nteract/papermill) for executing notebooks.

The [other ways to schedule Jupyter Notebook](https://mljar.com/blog/schedule-jupyter-notebook/) can be to use a web-based application for notebook scheduling:

- [Mercury](https://github.com/mljar/mercury)
- [Notebooker](https://github.com/man-group/notebooker)

Both of them can automatically execute the notebook in the background and share the resulting notebook as a website.