# How to setup Google Cloud Scheduler to run Google Colab?

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, google-colaboratory, google-cloud-scheduler

I've read a few threads here about how to schedule a Google Colab notebook to run and they all say use Google Scheduler, but while creating the Scheduler job it's completely not intuitive or obvious what to do or how to connect the job to the colab and how to make it run.

When creating the job you have three options as a target: HTTP, Pub/Sub and App Engine HTTP. Which do I pick? How do I setup either of those up for colab? I ended up choosing HTTP and just pasted in the colab URL. How does it actually run the colab. I am sooooo confused. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Its possible that this may be useful to you:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57561291/how-do-i-automate-my-jupyter-notebook-using-google-cloud

I believe that AI Platforms Notebook is an environment for running notebooks that can be governed by API execution and scheduling.  Google Colab is more a free development environment and sandbox rather than a production based story.

Comment: Have you found a solution to this yet? I've also got a Colab notebook (just one cell) and am trying to get Google Scheduler to run the cell.