# Automatically running a Jupyter notebook

Tags: python, automation, cron, jupyter-notebook, jupyter

I have a Jupyter notebook that scrapes web data and saves a dataframe to a csv. I would like to run this every day automatically. I am using a mac for this project.

I have looked around a lot (including here: [how to run a python jupyter notebook daily automatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48750055/how-to-run-a-python-jupyter-notebook-daily-automatically/49510178#49510178)), but as of yet I have not found a clear enough answer. I am quite new to all this, so I am looking for a step-by-step: like how you'd explain it to someone with no knowledge on cron etc.

Any advice would be much appreciated! Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why don't you just convert the jupyter notebook into a raw python file? You can use this command: `jupyter nbconvert --to script "[YOUR_NOTEBOOK].ipynb"` (replace `[YOUR_NOTEBOOK]` with your notebook name)

**EDIT:** You could also use [Juptext](https://github.com/mwouts/jupytext#command-line-conversion), as pointed out by @Wayne in the comments below.

### **If you *need* a jupyter notebook:**

1. Use [datalab](https://github.com/michaelchanwahyan/datalab) or [papermill](https://github.com/nteract/papermill)
2. Use the [SeekWall Chrome Extenstion](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/seekwell/mefkdbekccdbdihhondepjimindlbpfg)
3. Create a custom python script to launch jupyter notebook, and run that python script using the `Automator` app in your Mac

Comment: [Jupytext](https://github.com/mwouts/jupytext#command-line-conversion) on command line will allow you to convert to a script and back again, too. It can even execute notebooks, without requiring conversion.

Comment: Nice. I'll add that to my answer.